# Update calculations when child entry updated gravity form

Tags: gravityforms

The amazing gravity wiz team has prepared a [snipp](https://github.com/gravitywiz/snippet-library/blob/master/gp-nested-forms/gpnf-update-calculations-when-child-entry-updated.php) by which update calculations when child entry is updated, but I don't know what the problem is, it doesn't work for me!
My way of working is that I connected a form to its parent using the [code](https://github.com/gravitywiz/snippet-library/blob/master/gp-nested-forms/gpnf-attach-child-entry-programatically.php). When the form is sent, the entry is correctly connected to the desired parent, but I want the calculations of the parent form to be updated as well.